# Google analytics custom dimension never sent with gtag

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js, custom-dimensions

I read the [google doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets) and it seems easy to implement custom dimensions, however I tried and tried again and never been able to make it work.
My code:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-123456789"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-123456789', {  
                                        'custom_map': {'dimension1': 'inapp'}
                                    } );

    gtag('event', 'page_view', {  'inapp': '1' } );

</script>
```

I tried without the quotes for the value, I tried to add `'inapp': '1'` in the config, nothing works.
Is their something to activate, or same case it is not supposed to work ?

Comment: How do you know it didn't work? Did you create the custom dimension in GA?

Answer (score 4):

Your code is trying to send an event. To record a pageview with a custom dimension, try:

```
gtag('set', {'dimension1': '123'});
gtag('config', 'UA-12345678-1');
```